# How to initialise a state variable after the beginning of a simulation using Gillespie SSA?

Tags: r, simulation, modeling, stochastic

I've been trying to run a simulation using the GillespieSSA package in R. My model has 3 state variables, 2 of which have initial values of 1, and the last of which, I want to initialise at a time step after the beginning of the simulation.

```
x0 <- c(Pi = 1, Pj = 0, I = 1)
```

When running the same simulation using deSolve, someone on here suggested I initialise the last state variable by using an **event**, and that worked great!

```
eventdat <- data.frame(var = "Pj", time = 10, value = 1, method = "rep")
results <- lsoda(N0, TT, Model, p = parms, events=list(data=eventdat), verbose = TRUE)
```

I've tried implementing the same strategy within the ssa() function, with no success.

```
# method = "OTL"; optimised tau leap
TestOutput2 <- ssa(x0, a, nu, parms1, TT, method = "OTL", simName, events=list(data=eventdat),
                  verbose = TRUE,
                  consoleInterval = 0,
                  censusInterval = 0.1, 
                  maxWallTime = 30, 
                  ignoreNegativeState = TRUE)
...
Error in ssa(x0, a, nu, parms1, TT, method, simName, events = list(data = eventdat),  : 
  unused argument (events = list(data = eventdat))
```

I suspect that events aren't recognised by the ssa() function because of how ssa() implements tau-leaping? That said, I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to initialise one state variable after the beginning of a simulation using the ssa() function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I don't think either that events are recognized in the **GillespieSSA** package. It comes from other authors and has a completely different philosophy, so compatibility with **deSolve** cannot be expected. Both are contributed packages.

However, what you can do is to run a simulation until a certain time, then take the last states and start a new simulation. And, you can also try to write a function, that emulates the event mechanism of deSolve.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This makes sense, and yes, my work-around so far has been doing two simulations and concatenating them after-the-fact, which has worked, but isn't super efficient, so was hoping I was just missing something. Thanks so much!